# Exibir 6 dias anteriores

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal, sou iniciante no php e estou com um problema, alguem consegue me ajudar...

O codigo abaixo tem a função de mostrar todos os vencimentos da semana para pagamento de mensalidades. Só que ele encontra o dia do sábado (ultimo dia da semana) e mostra os 6 dias anteriores a ele.

O problema acontece quando o sabado cai no dia 1 ou 2 do mes seguinte, ai ele vai calcular dia 1 menos 6 e nao vai me gerar resultados nenhum. Conseguiram entender? Alguem consegue me ajudar nisso ?

Segue meu codigo..

```
<?php
    $seleciona = mysql_query("SELECT anoselecionado FROM anoselecionado LIMIT 1");

    while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona)){
        $anoselecionado = $ln['anoselecionado'];
    } 
?>
```

Restante:

```
<?php

    $dataatual = date('d/m/y');
    $partes = explode("/", $dataatual);
    $diaatual = $partes[0];
    $mesatual = $partes[1];
    $anoatual = "20".$partes[2];

    if ($mesatual == "1"){$essemes = 'jan';};
    if ($mesatual == "2"){$essemes = 'fev';};
    if ($mesatual == "3"){$essemes = 'mar';};
    if ($mesatual == "4"){$essemes = 'abr';};
    if ($mesatual == "5"){$essemes = 'mai';};
    if ($mesatual == "6"){$essemes = 'jun';};
    if ($mesatual == "7"){$essemes = 'jul';};
    if ($mesatual == "8"){$essemes = 'ago';};
    if ($mesatual == "9"){$essemes = 'setembro';};
    if ($mesatual == "10"){$essemes = 'outubro';};
    if ($mesatual == "11"){$essemes = 'nov';};
    if ($mesatual == "12"){$essemes = 'dez';};

    $sabado = 6; //sabado = 6º dia = fim da semana.
    $dia_atual=date('w'); //pego o dia atual
    $dias_que_faltam_para_o_sabado = $sabado - $dia_atual;

    $inicio = strtotime("-$dia_atual days");
    $fim = strtotime("+$dias_que_faltam_para_o_sabado days");

    $primdiasemana = date('d',$inicio); //data inicial
    $ultmodiasemana = date('d',$fim); //data final

    $seleciona = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensalidades WHERE (data_pagamento BETWEEN '".$primdiasemana."' and '".$ultmodiasemana."') and ano = ".$anoselecionado." and $essemes = 0 ORDER by id DESC");
    $conta = mysql_num_rows($seleciona);
    if($conta <= 0){
        echo "<center><div><h3>Não existem mensalidades pendentes com vencimento esta semana</h3></div></center>";
    }else{
        echo "
        <table class='table table-bordered' id='tabela-mensalidades'>
            <thead>
                <tr style='backgroud-color: #2D335B'>
                    <th style='width: 200px'>Aluno</th>
                    <th>Vencimento</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Serviço</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>";

        while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona)){
            $id = $ln['id'];
            $clientes_id = $ln['clientes_id'];
            $servico_id = $ln['servico_id'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: não deu pra entender não

Comment: Não deu para entender não. Sendo hoje `27/11/2018` qual resultado você espera. E para `30/11/2018` (caso em que o sábado cai no primeiro dia do mês seguinte)?